# Identify the DNX/Core process relative to an IIS website

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, dnx

I am running multiple ASP.NET Core web apps on a single IIS instance.

The problem I am having is that the DNX processes have a lock on the files so my deployment process fails.

How could I identify which of the underlying DNX processes relate to which IIS website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move to RC2 you can use app_offline.htm which will automatically stop your process and unlock your files. Given that dnx is dead you will have to move dotnet anyways.

Comment: Yes RC2 upgrade in the near future... Do you drop the .html file into IIS root to signal it to kill the dotnet process??

Comment: Yes. You drop app_offline.htm and the ASP.NET Core Module will stop the application and will display the content of the file. Once you remove the file your application will be started again on the first request (https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/81)

Comment: Today I finished a blog post about running Asp.Net Core apps with IIS where you can find more details: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/